# Unable to iterate through list for creating Key pair

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I'm trying to iterate and map list with a key pair. I'm getting the following output as below(i.e.) Im getting only the last value in the list.

```
{'first': [{'Key': 'Created', 'Value': '2020'}, {'Key': 'Type', 'Value': 'Entr'}], 'Second': [{'Key': 'Created', 'Value': '2020'}, {'Key': 'Type', 'Value': 'Entr'}]}
```

**Code**

```py
tags = [[{'Key': 'Created', 'Value': '2019'}, {'Key': 'Type', 'Value': 'Business'}], [{'Key': 'Created', 'Value': '2020'}, {'Key': 'Type', 'Value': 'Entr'}]]

samplelist = ['first','Second']

sampledict = {}

for i in samplelist:
    for tag in tags:
        sampledict[i] = tag
```

**Expected Output**

```
{'first': [{'Key': 'Created', 'Value': '2019'}, {'Key': 'Type', 'Value': 'Business'}], 'Second': [{'Key': 'Created', 'Value': '2020'}, {'Key': 'Type', 'Value': 'Entr'}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use dict and zip combination as follows:

```
dict(zip(samplelist, tags))
```

Note: You might not aware of that but you have one missing quote sign. tags should be like this:

```
tags = [[{'Key': 'Created', 'Value': '2019'}, {'Key': 'Type', 'Value': 'Business'}], [{'Key': 'Created', 'Value': '2020'}, {'Key': 'Type', 'Value': 'Entr'}]]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
tags = [[{'Key': 'Created', 'Value': '2019'},
         {'Key': 'Type', 'Value': 'Business'}],
        [{'Key': 'Created', 'Value': '2020'},
         {'Key': 'Type', 'Value': 'Entr'}]]

samplelist = ['first', 'Second']
sampledict = {}
i=0
while i < len(samplelist):
    sampledict[samplelist[i]] = tags[i]
    i += 1
```